# Problem in reshaping train and validation data for 1D CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I want to train 1D CNN on physioNet2017 ECG data. Each row in training data is of valiable length i.e, some rows are 9000 columns long and some are 18286 columns long. To make them of same length i have padded zeros to each row upto maximum length that 18286.
Now i have 20200 rows and each row is 18286 columns long so data shape is (20200, 18286). now i want to reshape this data in order to train 1D CNN. i have used following code for splitting the data into training and validation.

```
Xt, Xv, Yt, Yv = train_test_split(trainX_bal, trainY_bal, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)
print("Train shape: ", Xt.shape)
print("Valdation shape: ", Xv.shape)
```

and i have output:
Train shape:  (16160, 18286)
Valdation shape:  (4040, 18286)

Now i have reshaped the training and validation data using following code:

```
samples_train = list()
samples_val = list()
samples_test = list()
length = 8
for i in range(0,Xt.shape[0],length):
 sample = Xt[i:i+length]
 samples_train.append(sample)
for i in range(0,Xv.shape[0],length):
 sample_val = Xv[i:i+length]
 samples_val.append(sample_val)

data = np.array(samples_train).astype(np.float32)
data_val = np.array(samples_val).astype(np.float32)

print("Training new shape: ", data.shape)
print("Validation new shape: ", data_val.shape)

Xt_cnn = data.reshape((len(samples_train), length, data.shape[2]))
Xv_cnn = data_val.reshape((len(samples_val), length, data_val.shape[2]))

Yt = to_categorical(Yt, num_classes=4)
Yv = to_categorical(Yv, num_classes=4)
```

the output is:
Training new shape:  (2020, 8, 18286)
Validation new shape:  (505, 8, 18286)

Now i fit this data to CNN model using following code:

```
mod = cnn_model(Xt_cnn)
cnn_history = mod.fit(Xt_cnn, Yt, batch_size=64, validation_data = (Xv_cnn, Yv), 
                       epochs=20)
```

i get this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WReml.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reshaping is wrong. You are altering the number of samples so your data becomes incompatible with your labels. As I understand you are trying to reshape (1,18286) into  (8,18286/8) values which is impossible since 18286/8=2285,75. If you increase your padding and make shape 18288 then it becomes possible, since 18288/8=2286(since it's an integer).

You can do this reshaping as the following pseudo-code:

```
Arr=[]
for samp in range(number_of_samples):
    new_array=Xt[samp,:].reshape(8,2286)
    Arr.append(new_array)

Arr=np.array(Arr)
```

Arr's shape becomes (number_of_samples,8,2886)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. your solution worked but i have a confusion. why are you changing the shape of 18288, as these are the actual columns, so reshaping it won't affect the accuracy measures?

Comment: We need to arrange columns rather than rows because each row represents a sample corresponding to a y-label. If we would have arranged rows it would distort the sample-label correspondence.